# Annotation Query and return only specific nested field with spring data elasticsearch

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

Annotation Query and return only specific nested field with spring data elasticsearch

**Version**：

springboot:2.1.7.RELEASE

spring-data-elasticsearch:  2.1.7.RELEASE

elasticsearch: 6.5.4

---

document：

```
@Data
@Document(indexName = "test_book", type = "test_book")
public class Book {
    @Id
    private String id;

    private String name;

    private LocalDateTime time;
    /**
     *
     */
    private Publishing publishing;

    /**
     * 
     */
    private Author author;
}
```

Repository：

```
public interface BookRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<Book,String> {

    @Query("{" +
            "\"_source\": {" +
            "   \"includes\": " +
            "       [ \"name\"]" +
            "}," +
            "\"bool\" : {" +
            "   \"must\" : [{" +
            "       \"term\" : {" +
            "           \"id.keyword\" : \"?0\"" +
            "           }" +
            "       }]" +
            "   }" +
            "}")
    Book queryBookNameById(String id);
}
```

I just want to get the data of the **name**, which can relatively save memory resources. But I got an error, can’t I use it like this? Or can only use elasticsearchTemplate?

```
ParsingException[no [query] registered for [_source]
]
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.AbstractQueryBuilder.parseInnerQueryBuilder(AbstractQueryBuilder.java:332)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.WrapperQueryBuilder.doRewrite(WrapperQueryBuilder.java:165)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.AbstractQueryBuilder.rewrite(AbstractQueryBuilder.java:279)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.builder.SearchSourceBuilder.rewrite(SearchSourceBuilder.java:921)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.builder.SearchSourceBuilder.rewrite(SearchSourceBuilder.java:80)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.Rewriteable.rewriteAndFetch(Rewriteable.java:97)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.Rewriteable.rewriteAndFetch(Rewriteable.java:87)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.TransportSearchAction.doExecute(TransportSearchAction.java:215)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.TransportSearchAction.doExecute(TransportSearchAction.java:68)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction$RequestFilterChain.proceed(TransportAction.java:167)
    at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.action.filter.SecurityActionFilter.apply(SecurityActionFilter.java:126)
......
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This currently does not work with the `@Query` annotation for repositories. Spring Data Elasticsearch will wrap the value of the annotation as the *query* value and so includes the `_source` part into the query.

We would need to add additional parameters to the annotation (`includes` and `excludes`) to be able to build a correct query and make this work. I will create an Jira issue for this to keep track of this feature request.

[Jira issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAES-707)

Comment: This feature is more helpful